# Use struct as base for derived class in C++

Tags: c++, c, casting

Is it possible to have a class inheriting from a struct?

More specifically, how can I wrap a C struct with a class, so that I can pass class pointers to methods that requires struct ptr and cast back when I receive the pointer in e.g. callbacks?

(Or even more specifically, the address of the class should be same same address as the struct...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just derive from the C struct. In C++, the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that the latter's default member accessibility is `private`, while the former's is `public`.

If only single inheritance is involved, the `class`'s address should be the same as the `struct`'s which acts as a base class. If the inheritance only serves the implementation (that is, there is no Is-A relationship between the two), consider using private inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

yes, in C++ a class is a struct with default private members, and a struct is a class with default public members. Therefore a Class can be derived from a struct.

The choice on the method to wrap structure A in class B is the usual in OO design:
B is a A: use inheritance
B contains a A, use Composition: make A a memberof B.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a struct is a class in which members are by default public; that is,

```
struct person
{
};
```

is equals to:

```
class person
{
  public: //...
};
```

Another difference, that by default (without explicit access modifier) class inheritance means private inheritance, and struct inheritance means public inheritance.

```
struct person {...};
struct employee : person {...};
```

Means public inheritance, i.e. there is IS A relationship and implicit conversion between employee and person;

```
class person {...};
class employee : person {...};
```

Means private inheritance (i.e. employee IMPLEMENTED IN TERMS OF relationship and no implicit conversion between employee and person).

In your case classes and structs are interchangeable;